# Vector Source block in GNU Radio PSK tutorial

Tags: gnuradio, gnuradio-companion

I don't understand the inputs in the Vector Source block in the fourth flowchart in the GNU Radio Guided PSK Tutorial. What is behind the three dots?  Please state, in full, the input to the Vector line in the first couple of Vector Source blocks so that I can see and understand the inputs.  The tutorial is at: https://wiki.gnuradio.org/index.php/Guided_Tutorial_PSK_Demodulation.

[image: Flowgraph]

The problem I have is in the section called Recovering Timing.  There is no link to any file that explains the inputs to the Vector Source blocks.  The tutorial shows the surface of the block but not the input.  The surface shows 49*[0,]+[1,]+5...   and then the next one is 50*[0,]+[1,]+4...  I don't understand the input to these Vector Source blocks.

Comment: Can you link to that? Also, aren't the files from the tutorials available online?

Comment: yes, thanks, it's right here:

Comment: Um, you seem to have forgotten to include the link in your comment? Anyway, can you **edit** your question to include it?

Comment: thanks, it's right here: https://wiki.gnuradio.org/index.php/Guided_Tutorial_PSK_Demodulation, it's in the section called Recovering Timing.  There is no link to any file that explains the inputs to the Vector Source blocks.  The tutorial shows the surface of the block but not the input.  The surface shows 49*[0,]+[1,]+5...   and then the next one is 50*[0,]+[1.]+4...  I don't understand the input to these Vector Source blocks.

Comment: ... **edit** your question to include this. Don't post it as comment.

Comment: okay, edited question, thanks

Answer (score 1):

When we updated that tutorial to 3.8, it was decided that only the final flowgraph source would be included in the active gnu radio tree. However, all of the previous ones from 3.7 can be found in https://github.com/gnuradio/gr-tutorial/tree/master/examples/tutorial7  You can get the specific parameters there.

Also note that both the old and new versions of mpsk_stage6.grc were incorrect. Look at https://github.com/gnuradio/gnuradio/issues/3599 to find the solution. NOTE: As of 9 July 2020, that flowgraph has been incorporated into the gnu radio tree, so the link in the tutorial is correct.

Comment: Thanks, much appreciated.  Thanks to both of you.

Answer (score 0):

that's just a pythonic way of making vectors that are

```
0,0,0,0,…,0,1,0,…,0
```

`49*[0,]` is of the shape `integer * list`, and that just means "generate a list containing `integer` repetition of `list`. So `49*[0,]` is a list containing 49 zeros. You can append more lists using `+`.

Here, the first source contains data that's 49 zeros, followed by a single one, followed by more zeros (likely, 50).

The secons source contains 50 zeros, followed by a one, followed by more zeros (probably 49), and so on.

The idea here is just that they contain the same signal, but shifted!

Comment: But if I type in 49*[0,]+[1,])+50*[0,] or 49*[0,]+[1,])+50*[0,]+[1,] I get "invalid syntax."  I still don't understand what the input should be.

Comment: I don't understand why there'd be a `)` in your input. This is just normal Python.

Comment: and there's likely no trailing `+[1,]`.

Comment: it's accepting my inputs now, but I don't think I have the right inputs.  For the first one I have 49*[0,]+[1,]+50*[0,] and the for the second one I have 50*[0,]+[1,] + 49*[0,] and for the third one 51*[0,]+[1,]+49*[0,]